# Any way to get MS VC++ to abort after having x errors

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-construction

I am compiling dll's that take a long time, i was wondering if you could automatically make MSVC++ abort the compile after a certain number of errors.

For example an error in one header causes 100's of errors in the program but it can take a few minutes for the compilation to stop.

I know I can cancel it manually, but was wondering if I could get the compiler to go, you have had 20 errors, the compile is not going to work I give up?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a similar answer here for certain number == 1: [How to automatically stop Visual C++ build at first compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134796/how-to-automatically-stop-visual-c-build-at-first-compile-error). Perhaps you could modify [Eric Muyser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119301/eric-muyser)'s macro by changing this line:

```
If found > 0 Then
```

to something like this:

```
If found >= 20 Then
```