# How do I configure VS2008 to stop compiling when it hits X errors?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, user-interface

Maybe I'm remembering Borland's compiler?  But I seem to recall having the ability to set "stop compiling if X errors are encountered" - or some such.

VS2008 already stops on 100 errors.  But I'm already fixing the first couple, and hitting save, which causes the compiler to warn me about saving while compiling - which its being retarded to even create this situation.

Either: STOP compiling on ~10 errors,
Or:     STOP compiling when I hit save (during a compile).

I have found no setting which allows either of the above, but perhaps someone here knows if and where they may be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically stop Visual C++ 2008 build at first compile error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134796/automatically-stop-visual-c-2008-build-at-first-compile-error)