# How do I make Visual Studio automatically stop compiling after 1 (or n) errors?

Tags: visual-studio

For example, a missing semi-colon in C++ can result in hundreds of errors. Is there a way to stop compiling when the first error is hit?

Update: apologies, just realized this was a duplicate of [Automatically stop Visual C++ 2008 build at first compile error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134796/how-to-automatically-stop-visual-c-build-at-first-compile-error)

Answer (score 2):

Hit the stop button.

Or, apparently, you can setup it up to stop automatically: http://www.ehow.com/how_5025041_automatically-visual-studio-build-error.html

Comment: Hitting the stop button is not ideal as it doesn't always take effect instantly. 
I tried the macro in  your link; it's an improvement but still compiles a whole project so it still wastes time.
A macro by "ericmuyser" in the link works quite well, the only issue is the flickering it causes in the output window as it selects and deselects.