# How do I make Visual Studio automatically go to the first error in a build?

Tags: visual-studio, vsx, vs-extensibility

This is done manually by going to the "Error List" output window and double-clicking on the first error or pressing F8. Is there a way to automate this?

(I'm using C++ if that matters.)

Comment: Create a macro and assign it for shortkey, you'll save the double click

Comment: Also you probably can add post build command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vittore is on track...

In VS press Alt+F11 to open the Macros IDE. Under 'MyMacros' open 'EnvironmentEvents' module and below these three lines

```
'Event Sources End
'End of automatically generated code
#End Region
```

paste this Sub:

```
Private Sub BuildEvents_OnBuildProjConfigDone(ByVal Project As String, ByVal ProjectConfig As String, ByVal Platform As String, ByVal SolutionConfig As String, ByVal Success As Boolean)Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildProjConfigDone
    If Success = False Then
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.Cancel")
        Beep()
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Build failed!", "Build Events", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToNextLocation")
    End If
End Sub
```

Obviously, you can comment out or delete the Beep and the message box...

Comment: Thanks, the "DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToNextLocation")" line was what I was looking for. However this doesn't necessarily go to the first error - any idea how to prevent this event from being called more than once per build?

Comment: Found another post here at SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134796/how-to-automatically-stop-visual-c-build-at-first-compile-error) where they used OutputWindowEvents_OnPaneUpdated event instead...

Comment: Yes I'm using that technique (by Eric Muyser) to cancel the build. But it still has the same issue of being called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

*Adding to the previous answer:*

I suggest **`View.NextError`** command instead of `Edit.GoToNextLocation`. Do not get confused by its group (`View`), it actually **GOes TO error location in the editor**, like if you double-click error item in the error list.

You can also map it to the keyboard this way:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> = `View.GoToPreviousError`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> = `View.GoToNextError`

This will allow you to check for errors (and move between them in editor) even without need of displaying the error window and even without running the build.