# How to stop C# compile on first error in VS 2010 (VS 2008 macros don't work)!

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

> **New information**:
>   This question has been [re-asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041982/vs2010-how-to-automatically-stop-compile-on-first-compile-error/3042159) and has been correctly [answered by Noah Richards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041982/vs2010-how-to-automatically-stop-compile-on-first-compile-error/3042159#3042159) with a solution that works in VS 2010.

At work we have a C# solution with over 80 projects. Is it possible in VS 2010 to **automatically** stop compilation as soon as an error is encountered rather than the default behaviour which is to continue as far as possible and display a list of errors in the error window?

I'm happy for it to stop either as soon as an error is encountered (file-level) or as soon as a project fails to build (project-level).

I'd also note that in VS 2008 we used macros similar to some of the answers below but they don't work in VS 2010 (at least I couldn't get them to as the environment events don't seem to fire in VS 2010).

> **Also Somewhat Related:**
>   [How to automatically stop Visual C++ build at first compile error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134796/how-to-automatically-stop-visual-c-build-at-first-compile-error)

Comment: Not a duplicate as the question is for C#, not C++. Also this is specifically for VS 2010 as we have something that works for VS 2008 but it doesn't work in VS 2010.

Comment: Closing as duplicate is just redirecting someone to outdated information... it should be abolished altogether

Comment: @Andomar: too bad almost nobody else shares your opinion.

Comment: As this question has now been re-asked and answered correctly, I propose closing this as a duplicate of [the new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041982/vs2010-how-to-automatically-stop-compile-on-first-compile-error/3042159) that has the correct answer so searchers are appropriately forwarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question got closed as a duplicate so I re-asked it and it has been correctly answered by Noah Richards.

See this question [VS2010 - How to automatically stop compile on first compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041982/vs2010-how-to-automatically-stop-compile-on-first-compile-error/3042159#3042159) for a solution that works in VS 2010.

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl+Break should do the trick.

Comment: this does not answer the question.  Ctrl+Break stops the build at any time, not when the first error is encountered.

Comment: So, when it stops at any time, doesn't it stop when first error is encountered?

Comment: no it doesn't.  It stops when you press the keys.  It does not stop when the first error is encountered, unless you press the keys at the same time.

Comment: Ok, I agree that Your solution is probably better (but I haven't tested it), but in the question there is no clear indication on whether it should be compiler which stops building or any other option. Maybe for the case mentioned by Ben "Ctrl+Break" is enough (at least most of Us accept it as a necessary evil and live with it).

Comment: Its not my solution, as I stated its from another question, and anyway it didn't work and I have removed it.  It obviously isn't sufficient for Ben, as he asked specifically for a way to automatically stop the build, which this manual method isn't.