# .NET 4.0 Debugging Behavior

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

We recently migrated to VS 2010. We installed .NET 4.0 on our test machine. When we execute a console application that throws an unhandled exception, we no longer see the exception message and stack trace printed to the console but instead see the message

> An unhandled win32 exception occurred in something.exe [PID]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.

We do have the above setting enabled.

What do we need to do to return to the behavior we had previously?

Comment: Others asking the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134796/how-to-automatically-stop-visual-c-build-at-first-compile-error, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013209/how-to-stop-c-compile-on-first-error-in-vs-2010

Comment: @Don: Those questions are completely unrelated to the question here. Those questions concern compile-time behavior but mine concerns run-time behavior.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Just-In-Time Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx) check corresponding registry keys.

On my machine with Windows 7 x64:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"Debugger"="\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\vsjitdebugger.exe\" -p %ld -e %ld"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"DbgManagedDebugger"="\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\vsjitdebugger.exe\" PID %d APPDOM %d EXTEXT \"%s\" EVTHDL %d"
```