# Exiting out of a custom activity

Tags: c#, tfs

This might be a really simple question but I'm not finding anything [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-your-own-activity.aspx) to point me in the right direction.

I have a custom activity that has a few `trqycatch` blocks, and if it catches a certain error I want the activity to stop after writing to the build log.

What do I need to use to stop the activity or stop the build (I know they are probably different)?

Is it `application.exit`?

I also couldn't find information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.codeactivitycontext_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is the primary class I am looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial for how to create a custom logging activity should help with how to handle erros and log them, then stop the activity: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff859524(v=vs.100).aspx

As for stopping the build, this answer should do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042159/1446184