# C++ - template classes, header files and duplicate errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

When I have a class that's declared completely within a header file (templated types), and that header file is included by multiple cpp source files, compilation errors appear to be reported once per source file that includes the header. So, if I have a header that's used in 8 different places, each error is reported 8 times.

Suggestions? Do I have to live with this, am I doing it wrong, or what?

**Edit**

Aside from just being generally annoying, this also messes up the error popup when hovering over the red squiggly line in VS. Yay.

[image]

(Using Visual Studio 2012)

Comment: I rarely use visual studio, but could you not precompile the header and then only get the error once?

Comment: Is that actually an issue? Once the error is fixed, it'll disappear everywhere, no? Are those errors intentional, requiring them to stay there?

Comment: @Silas sounds interesting. I wasn't aware that was an option. Off to research.

Comment: @elusive for the most part, it's messy and annoying.

Comment: @DavidLively: Agreed, that is for sure. I was just wondering whether we are dealing with erroneous behavior from the compiler or IDE here.

Comment: You can [Automatically stop Visual C++ 2008 build at first compile error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134796/automatically-stop-visual-c-2008-build-at-first-compile-error)

Comment: @JasonEnochs yes. The errors are coming from separate cpp files that include the same header. (Verified by selectively removing source files and watching the error count)

Comment: Ok, then using a script like Oswald pointed out above is probably the only way to stop it.

Comment: @JasonEnochs if any of y'all would post an answer I'd happily accept it.

Comment: Credit should go to Oswald... or just go to the post he linked you to and up-vote that one.

Comment: @OSwald care to post an answer?

Comment: I did post an answer, but stackoverflow turned it into a comment automatically, because it thinks the answer was trivial :( I now voted to close as duplicate instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't really a duplicate. The referenced answer doesn't work for VS2012 as the Macro IDE has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

About your declared class, does it contain all you methods' definitions?

Whether it's a yes, then you should declare your functions outside your class and only leave the prototypes within your class, since you seem to be redefining them in each one of your includes causing an error, though you should provide us with more informations concerning the error you get..

```
//.h
//type as int, double or anything

template<type N>
class Foo
{
    public:

    template<typename T>
    void foo_fct();
};

//.cpp
#include ".h"

template<type N>
template<typename T>
void Foo<N>::foo_fct()
{
    //stuff here
}
```

this should fix the issue.

Comment: I'm already using that. The problem arises because the header is included by multiple CPP files, which are compiled independently. This isn't a multiple-inclusion problem.

Comment: yeah, then define your methods outside your classes in a .cpp file

Comment: You can define templated members in a CPP file, but you have to jump through hoops to avoid linker errors. When the compiler is evaluating a template, it needs information about the implementation. If it can't get it - for instance, if it's defined in another cpp instead of the header - you'll get linker errors.

Answer (score -1):

You're not allowed to include the same file multiple times. E.g

class foo 
include "test"

class bar
include "test"

class foobar
include "bar"
include "foo"

foobar will throw errors because it includes bar which will pull in test once then when it attempts to include foo it will attempt to include test again.

Comment: That is what include guards _guard_ against.

Comment: You must be a Pheonix